# .htaccess url rewriting and redirect 301

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect, url-rewriting

At the moment we have one page which shows a list of links
each link has got its own ID number

each link gets opened with the file info.php?ID=X

for example:

```
www.mysite.com/info.php?ID=1 shows  the link "weather italy"
www.mysite.com/info.php?ID=2 shows  the link "weather france"
```

Since we have several links for "weather italy" and  "weather france" we would like to rewrite new urls (weather-italy and weather-france) in .htacces
Whith the new urls we would have the folowing structure:

www.mysite.com/weather-italy/info.php?ID=1

www.mysite.com/weather-france/info.php?ID=2

With the following code we tell the server to rewrite the urls and call the original file:

```
RewriteRule    ^weather-italy/info.php?$    info.php    [NC,L]
RewriteRule    ^weather-france/info.php?$    info.php    [NC,L]
```

This works fine.

To avoid ***double indexing*** we want to redirect 301 the old link to the new link.

We have achieved that with the following code:

```
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?ID=1
RewriteRule ^info\.php$  http://www.touristinfo.fr/weather-italy/info\.php [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \?ID=2
RewriteRule ^info\.php$  http://www.touristinfo.fr/weather-france/info\.php [L,R=301]
```

This also does the job but combined with the first part of the script is produces a never ending loop.

What is wrong with our code?

Thanks a lot for your help :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`%{THE_REQUEST}` is supposed to only match if the url you want to match is an external request. Your problem is that the regex you made is not specific enough.

Let's examine what happens. You go to `example.com/info.php?ID=2`. The first two rules don't match, but the 4th one does. You end up with a redirect to `example.com/weather-france/info.php?ID=2`.

This goes through your `.htaccess` again. The second rule matches, and internally rewrites it to `info.php?ID=2`. The `[L]` flag doesn't make a difference here, because the url will be pulled through `.htaccess` until it stops changing. On the second cycle through `.htaccess`, the url will now match the 4th rule, even though the external request contained `/weather-france/info.php?ID=2`. `ID=2` is in the external request too, and the internal rewrite is now `info.php` again.

The fix is to make `%{THE_REQUEST}` match enough so that the rewritten url doesn't match it anymore.

**On a further note:** Familiar yourself with the difference between regex and strings in `RewriteRule`s and `RewriteCond`s. You escaped a dot in a string, while leaving a dot in a regex unescaped. The `?` is "match the previous character 0 or 1 times", not a question mark literal. The query string cannot be matched in the first argument of `RewriteRule`.

You'll end up with:

```
RewriteRule ^weather-italy/info\.php$ info.php [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^weather-france/info\.php$ info.php [NC,L]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /info\.php\?ID=1
RewriteRule ^info\.php$  http://example.com/weather-italy/info.php [L,R]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^(GET|POST)\ /info\.php\?ID=2
RewriteRule ^info\.php$  http://example.com/weather-france/info.php [L,R]
```

Comment: Using the code suggested by Sumurai8 it now redirects and writes the urls properly.

Comment: we still have one question though.
We would like to return the error code 301 when the old link is called, so we replaced R with R=301. The old link stil returns the code 200. Why does that happen? The purpose of the redirection was to return the code 301.

Comment: Does the url in the url bar change? If yes, then that happens with either a 301 or 302 status code. If not, clear your cache. You are most likely looking at the status code that is sent by `weather-country/info.php`, which should be 200.